# R shiny server: Error 500 can't set servers after they are sent?

Tags: r, server, shiny, shiny-server

Hey I'm new to Rshiny servers and I set it up but when I put in my new application I get the

```
       failed to render error 500 page: Can't set headers after they are    sent.
```

error , what could this mean(headers?) and how would I go about fixing it ?